# Problem ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch._C'

Tags: python, torch

I'm getting a `ModuleNotFoundError`. It says that there's no module named 'torch._C'. I don't know how to solve this error. What should I do?
I've included the traceback, maybe it helps (most recent call last):

```
File "/home/pi/Downloads/****/main.py", line 9, in <module>
    from run import process
  File "/home/pi/Downloads/****/run.py", line 4, in <module>
    from gan import DataLoader, DeepModel, tensor2im
  File "/home/pi/Downloads/*****/gan.py", line 4, in <module>
    import torchvision.transforms as transforms
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torchvision/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from torchvision import models
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torchvision/models/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .alexnet import *
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torchvision/models/alexnet.py", line 1, in <module>
    import torch.nn as nn
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/__init__.py", line 81, in <module>
    from torch._C import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch._C'
```

Could you please help solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem it's you have a folder named "torch" in the same directory :)

Try to change your position (cd ..) and run it python [.../yourfile.py]

Comment: in the same? I don't understand

Comment: what's the full path of your .py file?

Comment: My project files are located here /home/pi/Desktop/deep, and torch files are here /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch

Comment: If it is possible to write to me in a telegram, then @BoredGalt